# How to use @modyfi/vite-plugin-yaml or any library to import yaml file into JS object in Nuxt3 (import in a JS file)

Tags: yaml, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vite, nuxt3

I'm working on Nuxt3 project, I try using @modyfi/vite-plugin-yaml as a vite plugin to import yaml file but it's not working.

```
import ViteYaml from "@modyfi/vite-plugin-yaml";


// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  
  vite: {
    plugins: [ViteYaml()],
  },
});
```

With above config, I can import yaml file in vue component, but I cant import in a js file

import yaml file in JS file

```
import test from "./openApi/spec.yaml";

console.log(test)
```

error:
WARN  rollup-plugin-inject: failed to parse spec.yaml. Consider restricting the plugin to particular files via options.include

ERROR  RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)                            nitro 15:50:17

1: openapi: 3.1.0
^
2: x-stoplight:
3:   id: ko4ot8j7e9kl3

√ Nitro built in 833 ms

Answer (score 0):

Try installing package "js-yaml" along with "@modyfi/vite-plugin-yaml". Importing the .yaml file should work after this just like in yours example.